# Redirect after flagging as spam

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam

SE has a couple of [flags that cause post auto-deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work). This is a great feature that helps the community self-moderate with having to involve diamond-moderators. No complaints here.

I do think, however, the user-experience could be improved a bit for low-rep users.
The behavior today is top return to the post once a flag is cast. Usually, this is fine, but when a user without the "moderator tools" privilege (10K on regular sites, 2K on beta) raises the final flag needs to delete a post, he'll be returned to a 404 page.

This obviously isn't a critical bug, but it's annoying, and it makes novice users wonder what they did wrong - which is unfortunate, because we want to encourage users to flag spam and offensive posts. Perhaps, in such a scenario, could we redirect to a nicer page with a message down the lines of "thank you for flagging this post as spam, it has now been auto-deleted by the system"?

P.S.
If the problem statement wasn't stated clearly enough, as an reference, this just happened to with [this spam post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258148).

Answer (score 3):

I see your point, but redirecting (assuming to the homepage of the site?) might cause people to wonder "did my flag work?" or "what happened here?"

I know that's what I would wonder if I was a new user. The 404 error page isn't just an ordinary "Page Not Found", it contains extra information:

> This question was removed from Meta Stack Exchange **for reasons of moderation**.

Emphasis mine - when one see this,it's clear the spam flag worked.